# Qt 5.8 Cross Compile by arm-none-linux-gnueabi faild?

Tags: qt, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I downloaded arm-none-linux-gnueabi from CodeSourcery version 2011, after set path and config with this command

sudo ./configure \
      -opengl es2 -no-xcb\
      -release -silent \
          -continue \
          -opensource -confirm-license \
          -prefix  $DEVICE_PREFIX \
      -hostprefix $HOST_PREFIX \
          -sysroot $SYSTEM_ROOT  \
          -device $TARGET_DEVICE \
      -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} \
          -qt-libpng                         \
          -qt-libjpeg \
      -nomake examples \
      -nomake tests

Get this Error :

> executing config test use_gold_linker
>   + cd /home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/config.tests && arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -fuse-ld=gold -o conftest-out conftest.cpp
>    cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-fuse-ld=gold'
>   test config.qtbase.tests.use_gold_linker FAILED
>   executing config test verifyspec
>   + cd /home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/config.tests/common/verifyspec && /home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/bin/qt.conf "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += static console" "QMAKE_CFLAGS += --sysroot=/" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --sysroot=/" "QMAKE_LFLAGS += --sysroot=/" /home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/config.tests/common/verifyspec
>   + cd /home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/config.tests/common/verifyspec && MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/make
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp --sysroot=/ -O2 -O3 -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -I/home/amin/EMA/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-beagleboard-g++ -o verifyspec.o verifyspec.cpp
>   arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -mfloat-abi=softfp --sysroot=/ -Wl,-O1 -o verifyspec verifyspec.o   -lrt -lpthread -ldl 
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
>   /home/amin/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:64: recipe for target 'verifyspec' failed
>   make: *** [verifyspec] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation log shows that it was trying to use the `gold` linker, however the command was not found. The later error of missing libraries and object files presumably stem from this error.

[gold](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) is a relatively recent addition to the GNU toolchain, and you're using a fairly old version (gcc 4.6.1) so I would suggest upgrading your toolchain to the most recent one, unless you have really good reasons not to do so.

Comment: Thanks, I try to disable gold linker, but i didn't success

Answer (score 0):

Qt is quite opinionated when it comes to toolchain selection. There's a [list of supported compilers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html) which does not include something based on GCC 4.6. Given that Qt requires C++11 support these days, your chances of getting this working with an ancient compiler are severely limited.

Linaro provides [nice toolchains](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/) for download. Is there any reason why you are not using one? Alternatively, you also likely require some additional SW on your BBB, so chances are that you're using a distribution like Debian or a building tool such as Buildroot or Yocto for producing your images. BeagleBone Black is a mainstream platform with support provided by essentially anything targetting embedded platforms.

A TL;DR version: Update your toolchain or your build environment. Qt is no simple library.